# Laravel file permissions for Apache

Tags: php, laravel, apache, centos

I'm installing a Laravel app on a Centos 7 distro.  I'm using PHP 7.2 and I've successfully installed apache and my project.

I was able to get the Apache splash page to show but as soon as I point my virtual host to my laravel public folder I get file permission errors in apache2 logs.

I've made both my public and storage folders read/write/executable by all for a short period and I am still getting the errors.

My virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

DocumentRoot /var/www/html/checkers/public

<Directory /var/www/html/checkers/public>
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

My permissions (after temporary chmod 777 on public and bootstrap):

```
drwxr-xr-x. 13 root root   4096 Jul  6 03:16 .

drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root     22 Jul  6 03:16 ..

drwxr-xr-x.  6 root root    106 Jul  6 03:16 app

-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   1686 Jul  6 03:16 artisan

drwxrwxrwx.  3 root root     34 Jul  6 03:16 bootstrap

-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   1477 Jul  6 03:16 composer.json

-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 143918 Jul  6 03:16 composer.lock

drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root    247 Jul  6 03:16 config

drwxr-xr-x.  5 root root     72 Jul  6 03:16 database

-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    651 Jul  6 03:16 .env.example

drwxr-xr-x.  8 root root    198 Jul  6 03:22 .git

-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    111 Jul  6 03:16 .gitattributes

-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    155 Jul  6 03:16 .gitignore

-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   1022 Jul  6 03:16 package.json

-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   1134 Jul  6 03:16 phpunit.xml

drwxrwxrwx.  4 root root    116 Jul  6 03:16 public

-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   3675 Jul  6 03:16 readme.md

drwxr-xr-x.  5 root root     45 Jul  6 03:16 resources

drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     75 Jul  6 03:16 routes

-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    563 Jul  6 03:16 server.php

drwxr-xr-x.  5 root root     46 Jul  6 03:16 storage

drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root     83 Jul  6 03:16 tests

drwxr-xr-x. 37 root root   4096 Jul  6 03:22 vendor

-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    549 Jul  6 03:16 webpack.mix.js
```

The errors in /etc/httpd/logs/error_log:

> [php7:error] [pid 9120] [client 192.168.10.1:46658] PHP Fatal error: 
>   Uncaught ErrorException:
>   file_put_contents(/var/www/html/checkers/storage/framework/views/27ab4a7b5ea3854dc076406e3c218364a7743be0.php):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /var/www/html/checkers/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:122\nStack
>   trace:\n#0 [internal function]:
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2,
>   'file_put_conten...', '/var/www/html/c...', 122, Array)\n#1
>   /var/www/html/checkers/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(122):
>   file_put_contents('/var/www/html/c...', 's...', 0)\n#2
>   /var/www/html/checkers/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php(122):
>   Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem->put('/var/www/html/c...', 's...')\n#3
>   /var/www/html/checkers/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(51):
>   Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler->compile('/var/www/html/c...')\n#4
>   /var/www/html/checkers/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Vi in
>   /var/www/html/checkers/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php
>   on line 122 
>   [Fri Jul 06 03:41:01.295172 2018] [php7:error] [pid 9120]
>   [client 192.168.10.1:46658] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException:
>   file_put_contents(/var/www/html/checkers/storage/framework/views/27ab4a7b5ea3854dc076406e3c218364a7743be0.php):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /var/www/html/checkers/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:122\nStack
>   trace:\n#0 [internal function]:
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2,
>   'file_put_conten...', '/var/www/html/c...', 122, Array)\n#1
>   /var/www/html/checkers/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(122):
>   file_put_contents('/var/www/html/c...', 's...', 0)\n#2
>   /var/www/html/checkers/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php(122):
>   Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem->put('/var/www/html/c...', 's...')\n#3
>   /var/www/html/checkers/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(51):
>   Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler->compile('/var/www/html/c...')\n#4
>   /var/www/html/checkers/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Vi in
>   /var/www/html/checkers/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php
>   on line 122

**Edit:**  I've sudo chmod -R 777 /var/ (temporarily) and I still get these permission errors.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/file-permissions-for-laravel-5-and-others this may help you

Answer (score 1):

Assign the owner to all directories to your username and group to `www-data`. Assuming your apache group `www-data` and `my-user` is your username

```
sudo chown -R my-user:www-data /path/to/your/laravel/root/directory
```

Then change the file and directory permission like this

```
sudo find /path/to/your/laravel/root/directory -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;    
sudo find /path/to/your/laravel/root/directory -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

Details you can check here [File permissions for Laravel 5 (and others)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/file-permissions-for-laravel-5-and-others)

Comment: I've followed these instructions and I'm still getting the file permission errors.

Comment: did you check the laravel directory permission by using `ls -all` ?

Comment: Yes.  In fact, I did sudo chmod -777 -R to the entire /var/ directory and I still got those errors.  I'm a bit new at the server admin side so I'm kind of scratching my head.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help.  It turns out I was setting the permissions successfully but they were being overridden by Centos.

```
sudo setenforce 0
```

The above worked for me.

Answer (score -4):

Have you changed permissions recursively?

try:

```
chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/checkers/storage
chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/checkers/bootstrap
```